# Can I know how Activity was started by looking at crash stack trace?

Tags: android, android-activity, dependency-injection, stack-trace

I have a NPE and it seems that my Activity is started in some weird way/context as some components (constructed by dependency injection  - dagger 2 - which are normally instantiated and working well) are `null`. All I have is call stack trace with NPE on top of it.

So can I say that my Activity was created/recreated in some special way by examining this:

```
   //... and then all onCreate goes on and finally a NPE on top of it
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Did you check your setContentView is right place?

Comment: Looks like a regular Activity launch to me.